# can a MQTT Paho client be disconnected asynch?

Tags: callback, mqtt, paho

I have a **MQTT** Client (lets call it Client-1) using java PAHO, this is pub and sub to topics without problem,
on the other side of the globe I have another client (lets call it SuperClient) that can public topics as commands for my Clients...

one of those commands is "DISCONNECT-NOW", in my **Client-1** I have implemented the callback where I recieve correctly that msg, however, when I try to disconnect according to that command I get an Exception:

> ReasonCode: 32107
>
> Message: Disconnecting using a Callback-method is not allowed
>
> LocalizedMsg: Disconnecting using a Callback-method is not allowed
>
> Exception: Disconnecting using a Callback-method is not allowed (32107)
>
> Disconnecting using a Callback-method is not allowed (32107)
>
> at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:31)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms.disconnect(ClientComms.java:460)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.disconnect(MqttAsyncClient.java:632)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.disconnect(MqttAsyncClient.java:601)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.disconnect(MqttAsyncClient.java:608)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.disconnect(MqttClient.java:256)
>     at co.ve.de.MqttBroker.disconnect(MqttBroker.java:94)   at
>   co.ve.de.Implementation.lambda$1(Implementation.java:53)  at
>   co.ve.de.MqttBroker$1.messageArrived(MqttBroker.java:132)     at
>   org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsCallback.deliverMessage(CommsCallback.java:475)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsCallback.handleMessage(CommsCallback.java:379)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsCallback.run(CommsCallback.java:183)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

my question: is there any way to disconnect asynchronously from the network without doing some weird long polling ??

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try running the call to disconnect on a separate thread.

```
messageArrived(java.lang.String topic, MqttMessage message) {
  if (disconnect){
    new Thread().run(new Runnable(){
      public void run() {
        client.disconnect();
      }
    });
  }
}
```